# Why do Hall sensors saturate?

Tags: hall-effect

Can anyone explain to me what happens when a Hall sensor saturates (see graph underneath)? What is the physical cause? What happens to the electrons in the current to cause saturation? I can't find that information anywhere.

[image: hall saturation]

The reason I'm asking is because I am trying to build a rudimentary magnetic levitation device, but any time the electromagnet is turned on, the hall sensor saturates and does not react to anything else anymore.

Comment: Do you understand magnetic saturation? Do you understand that some sensors use ferrous materials inside? Or maybe you just mean signal voltage saturation?

Comment: could be saturation of the output amplifier... this question is really unclear.

Comment: what type of hall sensor is this?

Comment: All magnetic circuits can saturate.  All electronic circuits can saturate.  The graph shows saturation of the Hall sensor.

Comment: @Jasen its a 95A151

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yes, but why? I knw my hall sensor is saturating, I would like to understand the physical reason behind it.

Comment: I can't find that part, got datasheet?

Comment: The datasheet is this one, as far as I undertand https://docs.rs-online.com/dc97/0900766b8009a37c.pdf

Comment: Are you running with more than 60 mT?

Comment: Yes, cleary the electromagnet is too strong. I'd want to know what happens with the electrons inside the hall sensor to cause it to saturates. As far as I understand, the hall voltage is created by the magnetic field deviating the path of the electrons. So, with this explanation, how can saturation occur? Is it that the flow is deviated so much that the current cannot pass anymore (i.e. resistance going up to a limit value)?

Comment: The saturation is probably being imposed by the saturation of the amplifier (transistor) via the power circuit rather than the saturation of the hall sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing on Earth is infinite. At *some* point, things must stop. Specifically, if this sensor is powered by 5 V, of course the output cannot go up and up and up, above 5 V, right? Where would the extra volts come from? So the output has to stop somewhere below 5 V.

I know you're focusing on the physics of the material, which *are* a limitation. But the output of that sensor stops before you reach them. They stop when the output cannot exceed the supply voltage. The physical limitations of the magnetic material are not the reason for that flat top in that curve. The 5 V supply is.

What is "saturating" is not the material, it's a transistor.

> the hall sensor saturates

Switch to a different sensor, one with a lower "gain", so that it produces a lower voltage for a given magnetic input. If you must use that particular sensor, bypass some of the magnetic field around the sensor with iron or steel.